# plesk 10 - i have been deleting and adding subdomains but they still appear

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, subdomain

I added and then deleted few subdomains from the plesk admin control panel and now even though they are deleted they can be accessed through web browser and the initial plesk page is shown. Will this dissapear, or can I do something about it?? (like restart the dns, or httpd?) ah, please help i'm out of knowledge here :(

edit: Since the correct anser which helped me is in the comments, I'm posting it here so anyone searching for an answer won't have to read all comments:
@Bryan: just to let you know I've managed to get what I wanted with setting the second domain pointing to the same folder. And then I used .htaccess file to always show the www.subdomain.domain.com part. Anyway, your help is much appreciated, and once I get enough points here on SF I'll upvote for sure! Bye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Plesk panel is also the DNS server for your domain, then DNS records would have been created for those subdomains. If you accessed those subdomains, then those DNS records would be cached by your local DNS resolvers, and they could remain there for the duration of the TTL of the records you had created (even though the DNS records on your actual server no longer exist).

If all of the above is true, this will resolve itself over time. Additionally, you could try using different DNS resolvers or try from another location/computer.

Comment: @Bryan: I just took a look, and yes they do exist - automatically made I guess. How can I use different DNS resolver? Is it simple to test with the browser, or? Thx for your help and quick response.

Comment: Hello Nikola, is DNS for your domain hosted on your Plesk server? If you go to Plesk's DNS tool and look at the zone file for your domain, are the records for the deleted subdomains still there?

If you like, you can change your DNS resolvers on your local machine temporarily. Here are instructions to use Google's public resolvers: http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using.html

You may try clearing your browser's cache as well. CTRL+F5 reloads a page and bypasses the cache in Firefox.

If none of that works, have a friend go to the subdomain URL from his PC and tell you what he sees.

Comment: @Bryan: no they aren't there anymore after I delete the subdomain. Ok, thank you very much for the link. Now that I've changed the dns servers I get server not found which is what I wanted. Of course now I want for example that my www.subdomain.domain.com points also to subdomain.domain.com, but I've seen some links about this, so I'll take another shot at this tomorrow. Thank you for assistance. Oh, and if you maybe know a good answer/link for this www question in the last sentence I would appreciate it! Anyway I'll mark the answer as correct now as you've answered my main question.

Comment: Hey Nikola, you should be able to create two different sudomains and just use the same document root folder. In your control panel it should look like this: http://i.imgur.com/EPnlb.png That way requests for subdomain.domain.com and www.subdomain.domain.com both display the same content.

Comment: @Bryan: oh, yes! you're right that's how it can be done. Though I really wonder why my setting where I have a CNAME set like this www.subdomain.domain.com CNAME subdomain.domain.com.

Comment: @Bryan: just to let you know I've managed to get what I wanted with setting the second domain pointing to the same folder. And then I used .htaccess file to always show the www.subdomain.domain.com part. Anyway, your help is much appreciated, and once I get enough points here on SF I'll upvote for sure! Bye